# What is $\mbox{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: group-theory, modules

What is $\mbox{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$? Will it be cyclic always?

I cannot find it explicitly but I understand that there are $d(n)(=$ Number of divisors of $n)$ number of elements.I need it in modulo $\mathbb{Z}$ version.

Help me ,thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about group homomorphisms?

Comment: Z linear maps are same as group morphisoms

Comment: The group $\mathbb{Z}$ has one generator, say $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Any homomorphism $f \in \mbox{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/n)$ is thus determined by $f(1)$.

Comment: yes you are right @math137

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any commutative group $G$, you have an isomorphism $\,\,\varphi\colon \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbf Z, G) \simeq G$, defined by $\varphi(f)=f(1)$.

Comment: And this answer remains true even if you delete "commutative".